# How to score high of document containing "Burj Khalifa" in title and then in summary field in SOLR

Tags: solr

I want to sort document by relevancy i.e. First all docs having "Burj Khalifa" in title and then in summary field? and sort by publishdate as well. means latest documents must have high score.

criteria is like sort by score with publishdate

http://localhost:8080/solr/select?sort=score+desc,publishdate+desc&q=Burj Khalifa

Comment: Good for you. let us know when you have a question regarding this...

Comment: @Adrian Grigore and other closers: this is a perfectly valid question, even though not very clearly written. Please **don't** vote to close just because you don't understand the topic.

Comment: And please refrain from making such patronising comments, they don't help anyone and they hurt your reputation (your *real* one)

Answer (score 2):

I think you *don't* want sorting in this case, as it defines a strict ordering on the result set. Instead, I'd use [DisMax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxRequestHandler) with a [FunctionQuery](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) (see [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents) to boost newer documents) and the [qf parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxRequestHandler#qf_.28Query_Fields.29) to boost the title field.

You'll have to play a bit with the boost values to get optimal results.